# Tunneling effect - causes

Tags: quantum-mechanics, scattering, quantum-tunneling

I'm currently studying QM, and in my class [tunneling effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_tunnelling) was mentioned, but with no details.

I was wondering what exactly causes this effect?

Is this due to the wave characteristics of the particle, so that waves with appropriate momentum can pass through while the others can't?

or is it due to the uncertainty principle of energy-time?  perhaps it's both?
I was searching online, but all the information is vague and I can't find the exact explanation.

Thank you very much in advance!

Edit: I'm a university student, so I'm looking for more rigorous explanation

Comment: First see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_in_a_box & then https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_potential_well

Comment: You should mention at what level are you seeking explanation. In case you are a high school student, the answer could be more verbal than mathematical.

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna give a "short" answer which can be expanded by looking into Zettili's Quantum Mechanics book, or Bransden's or any other standard QM book.

When you study the one dimensional potential barrier problem when the energy of the particle $E$ is smaller than the barrier value $V_0$ ($E<V_0$), the time independent Schrödinger equation gives the form of the wavefunction of the particle in the different regions of the problem. The next figure can illustrate this situation.

[image]

In this fashion, the expression of the wavefunction in the different regions of space is
$$\begin{cases}
\psi_1(x)=a_1e^{ikx}+a_2e^{-ikx} & x\leq 0\\
\psi_2(x)=b_1e^{\rho x}+b_2e^{-\rho x} &0 \leq x \leq a \\
\psi_3(x)=ce^{ikx} & x\geq a\\
\end{cases}$$

I have eliminated a part of the third  wavefunction because we don't expect any wave travelling towards $x=0$ after the barrier. Also it is important to note that the exponentials are not always imaginary, but in the barrier region they are real. This happens because the Schrödinger equation will have  a different sign on a constant due to a term proportional to $V_0-E$.

After a big mathematical mess including continuity of the wavefunction and its derivative in the different particular points of our system $x=0$ and $x=a$, you can calculate, as in every one dimensional, time independent Schrödinger problem a reflection and transmission coefficients. The latter gives us a hint of the fraction of particles that can trespass the potential barrier. Its expression is the next one
$$T=\frac{4E(V_0-E)}{4E(V_0-E)+V_0^2\sinh^2(\sqrt{2m(V_0-E)}a/\hbar)}$$

So this coefficient will be near zero when $V_0>>E$ or $a>>1$. Obviously the classical result can be recuperated by making $\hbar \rightarrow 0$ or with a very high mass $m$. Adding up, this is a result of the wave-like properties of matter at very low scales.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your detailed explanation. Perhaps I wasn't clear enough, I meant something a bit different - I'm familiar with this scattering problem, what I'm trying to understand is what causes this, if there's an explanation to that, and not an example for the existence of the phenomenon

Comment: @E.Ginzburg Sorry if I didn't answer your question properly. The nature of this phenomenon is clearly the wave-like properties asigned to matter. By this I mean, reflection and transmission through matter is a purely wave property. This is a consequence of De-Broglie's postulate on matter behaving like waves.